Trouble coding Histogram
I'm new to R program, and I'd like some help with this code, I don't know where the error is, but I think is in the dataframe, I insert this code:
UcD<-c(41)
UcE<-c(38)
UdD<-c(80)
UdE<-c(80)
UpD<-c(78)
UpE<-c(74)
BD<-c(140)
BE<-c(133)
A<-c(76)
frA<-c(32)
Ax<-c(55)
frAx<-c(10)
Vl<-c(68)
Sa<-c(50)
Cl<-c(347)
Ce<-c(162)
To<-c(143)
Dados <- data_frame(Tipo_de_Osso)
dados <- data.frame(tipo_de_osso = c('UcD','UcE','UdD','UdE','UpD','UpE','BD','BE','A','frA','Ax','frAx','Vl','Sa','Cl','Ce','To'), quantia = c('41','38','80','80','78','74','140','133','76','32','55','10','68','50','347','162','143'))
ggplot(dados, aes(x=tipo_de_osso, y= quantia)) +
  geom_histogram()

and then I receive a message saying:
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.

What does that mean?
I was expecting my data displayed in a histogram graphic (I have ggplot2 installed)

Hi Marcello Silva. geom_histogram computes a count of the variable mapped to the x-axis. Since you already have counts of each bone type, maybe you just want geom_col()?
